# my trigger syntax doesn't work

Tags: mysql

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| attractionID   | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| attractionName | char(30)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description    | char(100)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ticketprice    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| packageNo    | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| attractionID | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| numTickets   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+---------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| packageNo     | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL       |       |
| passportNo    | varchar(30) | NO   | MUL | NULL       |       |
| fromDate      | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 |       |
| toDate        | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 |       |
| estimatedCost | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL       |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+


delimiter //
    create trigger estimatedCost_bi
    after insert on ticketBooking
    for each row
    begin
    set @package1=(select(sum(ticketprice*numTickets)
    from attraction join ticketBooking using(attractionID)
    join package using(packageNo) 
    where package.packageNo=new.packageNo);

update package join ticketBooking using(packageNo)

set estimatedCost = @package1

where ticketBooking.packageNo=new.packageNo;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

When posting questions in future, it really helps to include the error message.  Here it is.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from attraction join ticketBooking using(attractionID)

Your basic syntax error here is immediately before 'from attraction', we find

```
    set @package1=(select(sum(ticketprice*numTickets)
```

The problem here is that SELECT() is not valid syntax.  Correct syntax is SELECT followed by a space.  This appears to be an extra unmatched bracket, so you can simply remove it like so:

```
delimiter //
create trigger estimatedCost_bi
after insert on ticketBooking
for each row
begin
set @package1=(select sum(ticketprice*numTickets)
from attraction join ticketBooking using(attractionID)
join package using(packageNo) 
where package.packageNo=new.packageNo);
```

update package join ticketBooking using(packageNo)

set estimatedCost = @package1

where ticketBooking.packageNo=new.packageNo;
end//
delimiter ;